# Python zipfile compress_size returns 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am trying to get the compressed size of a file with Python and zipfile

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
namelist = zip.namelist()
for fn in namelist:
    print fn
    print zip.getinfo(fn).compress_size()
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZipInfo.compress_size](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipinfo#zipinfo-objects) is a simple `int` attribute, not a method, so you just need to do

```
print zip.getinfo(fn).compress_size
```

BTW, it's a Bad Idea to use `zip` as the name of a variable, as it's the name of a built-in function.